# Beautiful Soup to extract Chemical Names

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the chemical names (All in CAPS lock) from the below URL.

https://www.legislation.gov.au/Details/F2020L01255

I am interested in the chemicals that is shown in Schedule 4.

```
import requests
import re
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url = 'https://www.legislation.gov.au/Details/F2020L01255'
headers = {"Accept-Language": "EN-AU, en;q=0.5"}
results = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

chemicals = []

chems_div = soup.find_all('div', class_='WordSection7')
```

I am stuck from here. The chemical names is wrapped around a P tag with class='MsoNormal' and Span tag with lang='EN-AU'.

Comment: Do u only want the chemical names? Or is it ok if u get the description that is with it?

Comment: @Sushil, it's ok if description is included

Comment: Ok...I will provide u the code within 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.legislation.gov.au/Details/F2020L01255'
headers = {"Accept-Language": "EN-AU, en;q=0.5"}
results = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")
chems_div = soup.find('div', class_='WordSection7')
all_spans = [
    t.getText(strip=True) for t in
    chems_div.find_all("span", {"lang": "EN-AU"})
]

print([w for w in all_spans if w.isupper() and w != "SCHEDULE 4"])
```

Output:

```
['ABACAVIR.', 'ABATACEPT.', 'ABIRATERONE ACETATE.', 'ABCIXIMAB.', 'ABEMACICLIB.', 'ACALABRUTINIB.', 'ACAMPROSATE CALCIUM.', 'ACARBOSE.', 'ACEBUTOLOL.', 'ACEPROMAZINE.', 'ACETARSOL.', 'ACETAZOLAMIDE.', 'ACETOHEXAMIDE.', 'ACETYL ISOVALERYLTYLOSIN.', 'ACETYLCARBROMAL.', 'ACETYLCHOLINE.', 'ACETYLDIGITOXIN.', 'ACETYLMETHYLDIMETHYLOXIMIDOPHENYLHYDRAZINE.', 'ACETYLSTROPHANTHIDIN.', 'ACIPIMOX.', '# ACITRETIN.', 'ACLIDINIUM BROMIDE.', 'ACOKANTHERA OUABAIO.', 'ACOKANTHERA SCHIMPERI.', 'ACRIVASTINE.', 'ADALIMUMAB.', 'ADAPALENE.', 'ADEFOVIR.', 'ADIPHENINE.', 'ADONIS VERNALIS.', 'ADRAFINIL.', 'AFAMELANOTIDE.', 'AFATINIB DIMALEATE.'
and so on...
```